# Automatically set uploaded image label as product name in Magento?

Tags: magento

In Magento, when I'm creating a product from Catalog -> Manage Products -> Add Product, after I have uploaded the images in the Images tab, I have always have to enter the label text for each of the images, mostly having to copy the product name and paste it into every one of them.

My question is, **is there any way for Magento to auto-populate the image label as product name after I have uploaded the images?**

Thus far I tried adding JavaScript to the end of */app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml* for the label input text to grab the value of <input id="name" /> but it doesn't work because the label input is not loaded when the page loads but only after image uploads...

Any idea I could get this done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just edit your template file that displays the images to set the image label to the product name?

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml should be the file you would have to modify to make that happen. (The path could be different based on your Magento configuration)

Comment: Further you can use Mage::registry('current_product') to get model of the current product. So if you did $prod_model = Mage::registry('current_product') you could then use: echo $prod_model->getName()

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. However, there's a lot more places other than the individual product page where product images are being displayed, such as in category list, search results, reviews list, reviews, related products list, up-sell list, etc.....I don't think editing media.phtml would be an once and for all solution. And we won't be able to use different image labels (not the product name) if we hard code it in media.phtml....Any other ideas?

Comment: I would find an event related to saving a product. Something like catalog_product_save_before and use that to change the label for the image. If there is no event for that, then I would change all the template files for that. Another alternative would be to just write a script that goes through the visible products and updates the image labels to be the product name. (these others are backup plans in the event you cannot find an event to inject your change)